# When should I use NSKeyedArchiver instead of SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, memory, storage, record, nskeyedarchiver

I'm writing an iPhone app, which needs to store about 10 records, each takes up 20-200 KB space. I need to choose between NSKeyedArchiver and SQLite. My questions are:

1. Which takes up less space to store?
2. Which one is faster to read into memory? Which is faster to write back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For only 10 records, it will be much easier to use `NSKeyedArchiver`. SQL is for more intense database tasks in the hundreds of thousands of records, usually. I'd say it may not be worth the time to code that up unless you really need it.